# The battery life of the case of my AirPods Pro 2 is four days - is that expected?

Tags: battery, airpods

I have owned AirPods, AirPods 2 and recently AirPods Pro 2.  The battery life on the cases on the original AirPods and AirPods 2 usually lasts far longer than a week, in fact I haven't used my AirPods 2 much since I bought the Pro 2's and they have been sitting on my desk for weeks.  I just checked the case battery level and it's about 28%.

The Pro 2's however seems to be a different situation altogether.  I find that I have to constantly charge the case.

So, I measured the drain and (by chance) I didn't use the AirPods during the duration of the test (except for 15 mins once.)

The case went from 100% to 0% in four days.

Is this normal?  Am I just spoiled by the insane battery life of the older models' cases?

Thanks

[image: Battery Drain chart]

Comment: What’s the age of the AirPods Pro 2?

Comment: Five months old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a suggestion from somewhere else and it worked.

Apparently this is a firmware issue and can be resolved by resetting the AirPods

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT209463

I can confirm that this worked for me.